# java-how to scroll a jpanel?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to add jpanel to jscrollpane, then add jscrollpane to contentpane, but it doesnt worked,i reading around here, most peple say add the jpanel to jscrollpane, but i still cant scroll it..

[image]

```
package org.redeagle.growtopiamarket;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 461, 540);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 436, 493);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        contentPane.add(sp);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        try {
            URL urls = new URL("https://growtopiajson.000webhostapp.com/gtpost.xml");
            URLConnection conn = urls.openConnection();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("post");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String strImageURL = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imageurl").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String strItemName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("itemname").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String strItemDesc = eElement.getElementsByTagName("itemdesc").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String strItemPrice = eElement.getElementsByTagName("itemprice").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String strItemSeller = eElement.getElementsByTagName("itemseller").item(0).getTextContent();

                    JPanel postPanel = new JPanel();
                    postPanel.setBounds(10, 11, 425, 94);
                    panel.add(postPanel);
                    postPanel.setLayout(null);

                    JLabel image = new JLabel("");
                    image.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 94);
                    Image images = null;
                    try {
                        URL urlss = new URL("http://www.growtopia.in/images/seeds/seed-info/house-entrance-block.png");
                        images = ImageIO.read(urlss);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(images).getImage().getScaledInstance(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
                    postPanel.add(image);

                    JLabel itemName = new JLabel(strItemName);
                    itemName.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 21));
                    itemName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    itemName.setBounds(100, 0, 315, 32);
                    postPanel.add(itemName);

                    JLabel itemDesc = new JLabel("<html><p>" + strItemDesc + "</p></html>");
                    itemDesc.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    itemDesc.setBounds(100, 28, 315, 40);
                    postPanel.add(itemDesc);

                    JLabel itemPrice = new JLabel(strItemPrice);
                    itemPrice.setBounds(100, 69, 138, 14);
                    postPanel.add(itemPrice);

                    JLabel itemSeller = new JLabel(strItemSeller);
                    itemSeller.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    itemSeller.setBounds(248, 69, 167, 14);
                    postPanel.add(itemSeller);

                    panel.add(postPanel);
                }
            }    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several problems ganging up on you

- You're setting the bounds of the JPanel -- it cannot change its size now thanks to this, and this can prevent it from scrolling.
- You're using some `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` a dangerous and problematic thing to do with any Swing GUI but especially when trying to get scrolling working, and is something that will not increase the preferred size of components, which can prevent scrolling.

For JScrollPanes to work well, the size of the contained component must be larger than the JScrollPane's viewport, and that isn't happening in this situation.

I recommend that you get rid of null layouts, that you avoid constraining the size of the scrolled JPanel as you're doing, and then try it again.

Other problems:

- You appear to be re-reading the *same* image over and over again within the for loop, something that is wasteful and unnecessary. Read the image in *once*, create your ImageIcon with it, and store it in a variable. The Icon can be re-used on many JLabels.
- Your image suggests that you may want to consider using a JTable for display of the collected data.